# Can't get value from the circular python's list

Tags: python

I have an empty list, then I'm creating a circular link and trying to get this list by index, but getting IndexError. Why this happening? Should it be possible for me to get this list forever? How can I get value from this list?

```
>>> a = []
>>> a = [a]
>>> len(a[0])
0
>>> a[0][0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: `a[0]` is empty - what do you expect?

Comment: What do you expect this code to output?

Comment: What I'm expecting is that its possible to get the left side list from a[0] and then again and again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your list isn't circular, it's just an empty list within a list.

```
>>> a = []
>>> a = [a]
>>> a
[[]]
>>> len(a)
1
>>> a[0]
[]
>>> len(a[0])
0
```

You seem to have a misconception about how assignments work. `a = [a]` evaluates the right hand side first, which is `[[]]` and then the name `a` is rebound to that value.

You can get a circular list via

```
>>> a = []
>>> a.append(a)
>>> a
[[...]]
```

Of course it has length one, because there's only one thing in `a`: `a`.

```
>>> len(a)
1
```

Comment: So, there is no way to create an infinity linked list?

Comment: @IgorAlex Something different than the circular list I showed?

Comment: @IgorAlex then please define "infinity linked list".

Comment: @timged List that has a link to himself. Infinity in this case, possibility to go deeper and deeper in this list, without limitations. Correct me please, If not clear.

Comment: @IgorAlex You can do `a[0][0][0]...` arbitrarily deep with my example.

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because the initial `a` is empty. After the 2nd line of your code, you have:

`a=[[]]`. As such, `a[0] = []`, i.e an empty list. And `a[0][0]` is trying to access an element in an empty list which is why you see the error.